# RTP-Server in Android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rtp, stagefright

Working on Android 4.0+ above.

I am in process of analyzing ways to live stream my camera video to Window PC using RTP , encoding MPEG-2.

1. Is there readily available "rtp-server" in  android 4.0+ ?
2. Is following true:: "The Android platform lacks support for
       streaming protocol, which makes it difficult to stream live audio /
       video to Android enabled devices." extracted from [website](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml)
3. Currently I analyzed  used the ffserver from the ffmpeg
       libraries, but the FPS is < 5. which is far slow. Did any one
       explored other solution which has more FPS?
4. Did anybody tried using StageFright for same? Capturing raw data
   from camera and sending it to stagefright framework for encoding and
   then streaming the same using RTP ??

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your questions are as below. Though the links are related to `Android 4.2.2`, the same is true for `Android 4.0` also.

1. Yes, there is a `RTP` transmitter available. You could look at this example in [`MyTransmitter`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/rtsp/MyTransmitter.h) as a starting point or you can consider using the standard recorder as in [`startRTPRecording`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/StagefrightRecorder.cpp#765).
2. You can stream data via `RTP` from an `Android` device to an external sink or you could have a different use-case as in `Miracast` a.k.a. `Wi-Fi Display`. However, streaming from one `android` device to another device through `Wi-Fi Direct` is still not completely enabled. The latter statement is mainly coming from `Miracast` scenario.
3. You can use the standard `android` software, which is capable of high resolution recording and transmission. This is mainly dependent on the underlying hardware as the overhead from software stack is not very high.
4. Yes. This is already answered in Q1 above.